# Make all options required

Tags: sql, opencart

My opencart client didn't make all the options required, which means that the client can check out without having to select a size or color, etc.

Is there a way to update this without have to manually update the product in the admin? I have searched the SQL database to see if there is a required file but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQL you could use

```
UPDATE `product_option` SET `required` = 1
```

That assumes you don't have a table prefix. If you do, change `product_option` to `your_prefix_product_option`

Comment: Thanks for that Jay. Going to give it a go and will report back!